# Best Datepicker for feeding 'pickable' dates

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery datepicker plugin that I can 'feed' available dates.

Example input:
22-01-2017
23-01-2017
28-01-2017
02-02-2017

Output:
-a datepicker that only allows the dates from the example input.

Daterange wouldn't really work here, as certain dates could be skipped. Does anyone know a (customizeable) jquery plugin that allows this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my plugin here: https://codecanyon.net/item/caleran-date-range-picker/19454049

And there's a disableDays filter in the plugin, you can use it backwards to enable the days you want.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#caleran").caleran({
    disableDays: function(day){
      var enabledDays = [
         moment("22-01-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY"), 
         moment("23-01-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY"),  
         moment("28-01-2017 ", "DD-MM-YYYY"), 
         moment("02-02-2017", "DD-MM-YYYY")
      ];
      return $.grep(enabledDays, function(d){ return d.isSame(day,"day"); }).length > 0;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Demo here: http://rettica.com/caleran/docs/readme.html#custom-disabled-ranges-with-callback-